# Subsite change automatic logs me out

Tags: authentication, site

The situation:

- We have 2 subsites: /FR and /EN
- When logged in as administrator in /FR, and you change to /EN subsite, the subsite logs me out.

Is this because it's a whole new subsite and the authentication process isn't handled from ~/ or could be the problem?

Comment: Do you mean that you can still log in and get access under the same account, you just get prompted for authentication?

Comment: While being on /FR and going tot /EN, SharePoint logs me out and doesn't prompt me for authentication. It just logs me out so that I'm a normal visitor (no credentials required)

Comment: I know this will sound obvious what happens when you clik ctrl+F5 on that same page - does it then show you logged in? Is this a publishing site and are you using page output caching using cache profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

- Checked my Quick Launch and the links on /FR were with http://www.foo.org and on /EN they were without the 'www', just like: http://foo.org

Thanks for helping me out though!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using page output caching, it could be that your cache profiles are not set up to cache differently for authenticated users and you are getting a cached version of the page.

Clean out your browser cache to see if the issue goes away.

Comment: This is probably better suited as a comment to the PO.

Comment: Removing cache and/or Ctrl + F5 doesn't help for me, removed everything from Temp, closed the session (browser closed) and so on didn't help either.

Comment: What about output caching - are you using page output caching in your site (needs to be a publishing site to do this?)

Comment: We don't use page output caching

Comment: I see that the /EN/Default.aspx (first page you go to after changing SubSites) is acting normal (still logged in as Administrator) but when I navigate towards to other pages (in /SharedDocuments) the case of getting logged out raises up.

Comment: I hope this issue can be solved, since this isn't quiet User-Friendly.

Comment: Can you compare the Permission on Both subsite. you have admin right is that mean as Site collection admin(not site owner).

Comment: Permissions are the same on both subsites. 
I think it's quiet strange that when you're logged in one subsite and when you navigate to the other subsite it logs you out after changing (no matter which) page. 

Could it be that my root-site redirects to /FR and the authentication is only handled at /FR and /EN inherits from / and i'm not authenticated there?